Replicating Windows Run behavior using either `CreateProcessW` or `ShellExecuteExW`?
The Windows Run dialog (Win+R) is used to launch arbitrary programs from a user-inputted string. What's cool about it is that it can handle spaces in the program path without any escaping.
So for example, this works fine: C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash --cd=./bin. With CMD or Powershell, C:\Program would be interpreted as the program path, and the rest as arguments.
Can this behavior of launching a program from a string that might have spaces in its path be replicated using CreateProcessW or ShellExecuteW? ShellExecuteW needs a separate parameter for the program path and its arguments, which seems tough to work-around with paths that may have spaces. CreateProcessW without passing an lpApplicationName seemed like it could be the solution, but I can't get it working (sample code in Rust below - responses with any lang are fine of course).
use windows::core::PWSTR;
use windows::Win32::Foundation::CloseHandle;
use windows::Win32::System::Threading::{
  CreateProcessW, PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS, PROCESS_INFORMATION,
  STARTUPINFOW,
};

pub fn shell_exec() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  // Arbitrary command to execute. The command in the variable doesn't work
  // but this path does: r#"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash"#;
  let command = r#"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash --cd=./bin"#;

  let command_utf16: Vec<u16> =
    command.encode_utf16().chain(Some(0)).collect();

  let mut si = STARTUPINFOW::default();
  let mut pi = PROCESS_INFORMATION::default();

  unsafe {
    CreateProcessW(
      None,
      PWSTR(command_utf16.as_ptr() as *mut u16),
      None,
      None,
      false,
      PROCESS_CREATION_FLAGS::default(),
      None,
      None,
      &mut si,
      &mut pi,
    )?;

    println!("Command executed successfully.");
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)?;
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread)?;
  }

  Ok(())
}


possible use SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate
SHSTDAPI SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate(
  _In_ PCWSTR pszCmdTemplate,
  _Out_ PWSTR  *ppszApplication,
  _Out_opt_ PWSTR  *ppszCommandLine,
  _Out_opt_ PWSTR  *ppszParameters
);

which exactly design for this purpose

The documentation you linked says:

The lpApplicationName parameter can be NULL. In that case, the module name must be the first white space–delimited token in the lpCommandLine string

So let command = r#"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash --cd=./bin"#; would be interpreted as the command C:\Program with the parameters Files\Git\git-bash and --cd=./bin
The run dialog does it's own parsing of the input (it can also accept URL/URI or any real paths for example) which you have to replicate.

Are there any winapis to make that parsing easier? My first thought would be to split on white spaces, and iterate from the start of the string until a valid file path is found (or if the file name exists in PATH).

None that I know of, what you describe would be my approach as well, though thing.exe might not get detected by thing albeit being runnable with the run dialog.

@L.Berger CommandLineToArgvW() parses a command line following a specified set of rules.

The documentation also states that it will try different paths until it finds a match or exhausts possibilities. You can verify this with procmon to see what paths it tries and why they fail.

yes, used complex parsing for take exe path to "" https://i.imgur.com/RoZoLoZ.png

@IInspectable Getting the following from CommandLineToArgvW: ["C:\\Program", "Files\\Git\\git-bash", "--cd=./bin"]

@RbMm The SHEvaluateSystemCommandTemplate from your screenshot is working great though! It manages to parse C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe as the program and --cd=./bin as the args. That can then be passed to ShellExecuteW to get the same behavior as Windows Run (except for with URIs or real paths like @cafce25 mentioned). Do you want to post it as an answer and I can accept it?
